# Set Height for AdView banner on latest Admob version

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I am using latest admob version (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals - the Google Play version) for my application. i wanna set height for my AdView banners (BANNER and SMART_BANNER in AdSize). But i can find out any methods or any ways to set it. I have followed exactly the guide from google admob site.

Thank you.

New edit : 
This is my implementation :

```
adView = new AdView(m_context);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(m_context.getString(R.string.admob_id));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
wrapper.addView(adView, param);
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20489433/3036759

Answer (score 0):

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
```

See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i already tried this one. I would like to set specified height for my AdView. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about what behaviour you are seeing because the above code will set the size of the ad. NB when you  provide LayoutParams to addView() you should provide the height as WRAP_CONTENT not MATCH_PARENT.